# Finding the rank of the Given string in list of all possible permutations with Duplicates

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ranking

I was trying to find the Rank of the given string in the list of permutations and was hoping someone can find the bug.

```
function permute() {
    var W = $('input').val(),
        C = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) C[i] = 0;
    var rank = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < W.length; i++) {
        C[W.charCodeAt(i) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)]++;
    }
    var repeated= 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        if(C[i] > 0) {
            repeated *=  fact(C[i]);
        }
    }    

    if (W !== '') {
        for (var i = 0; i < W.length; i++) {
            //How many characters which are not used, that come before current character
            var count = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
                if (j == (W.charCodeAt(i) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0))) break;
                if (C[j] > 0) count++;
            }
            C[W.charCodeAt(i) - 'a'.charCodeAt(0)] = 0;
            rank += ( count * fact(W.length - i - 1) );
        }
        rank = rank/ repeated;
    }
    var pp = 'Rank of  :: ' + W + ' -- ' + rank;
    $('div').append('<p>' + pp + '</p>');
}

function fact(n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 1;
    else return fact(n - 1) * n;
}

$('button').click(permute);
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/QV5LF/10/)**

A use case for this might be

`bookkeeper` is supposed to give a rank of **10743**.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have a test case to show the error?

Comment: `bookkeeper` is supposed to give a rank of 10743.. But i think I have messed it up

Comment: That's quite an obvious error when you give it `bookkeeper`... You should edit it in, so that other people might notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QV5LF/13/):

For each position check how many characters left have duplicates, and use the logic that if you need to permute n things and if 'a' things are similar the number of permutations is `n!/a!`

Comment: I think it still gives the wrong rank.. A use case might be `bookkeeper is supposed to give a rank of 10743.`

Comment: Why is abab 4? 1 is aabb, what is 2 then?

Comment: oops.. sorry it should be 2 .. My bad

Comment: @Sushanth--:Please check now

Comment: awesome.. I generally take more time to write a simple for loop and you came up with the entire logic .... !!!!

Comment: @Sushanth--: I have done this problem long time back, so it helps.

Comment: @Aravind: You have not used `count` anywhere in the demo fiddle but you have declared it. Why?

Comment: @crisron: You are right: the count variable is not necessary. Please ignore it.