# lexicographic rank of a string with duplicates

Tags: java, string, algorithm, permutation

Before marking duplicate please read this:

> I know this question has been asked before on stackoverflow . My
>   purpose is know where am I making mistake while implementing the same
>   logic. I have explained my logic in the last part. Also I am asked
>   this question on codereview.stackexchange but I'm not getting any
>   responses. I have tried a lot to find the mistake but couldn't come up
>   with anything.

```
 Given a string, find its rank among all its permutations sorted
 lexicographically. For example, rank of “abc” is 1, rank of “acb” is
 2, and rank of “cba” is 6. Assuming there can be duplicate characters.
```

MyCode:

```
public class Solution {
public int findRank(String A) {
  int n = A.length();

  long rank = 0;
 HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
   int x=0;
   int repFact=0;
   hm.clear();
   //find number of permutations placing character smaller than A[i]   
     at ith position , we call it 'x'
   for (int j = i+1; j<n ; j++) {
    if (A.charAt(i) > A.charAt(j)){
    x++;

    //put all the frequency of repeating characters in a Map 
    if(hm.containsKey((Character)A.charAt(j))){
       hm.put((Character)A.charAt(j),hm.get((Character)A.charAt(j))+1);
    }
    else
        hm.put((Character)A.charAt(j),1);


}

}

//Mod 1000003 to keep the number smaller
rank = (rank + x*((fact(n-i-1))))%1000003;
System.out.println("Rank = "+rank);
repFact =1;
if(!hm.isEmpty()){
Iterator it = hm.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    repFact  =(repFact * fact((int)pair.getValue()))%1000003;
    it.remove();  //to avoid concurrentModificationException


}
}

//permutation with repetation formula concept
rank = rank/repFact;

 }
return (int)rank+1;
}



public static int fact(int n){
    int  fact =1;
    while(n>0){
        fact=(fact*n)%1000003;
        n--;
    }
    return fact;
}
```

}

Logic is simple:
start from first character and traverse till end. find how many characters are ranked before this, suppose this is x, now we know there are x * (n-1)! permutations are ranked above this.
Repeat the procedure for every character in string.

To work for duplicate characters, find all the characters that are smaller (include equal this time also), do the same as above but, this time divide the rank so formed by p! where p is the count of occurrences of the repeating character.

Now for a string bbbbaaaa, the expected output is 70 but the above code is printing 6. Now I'm not able to find the loop hole in the code as the logic and its implementation seems good to me. 
Can anyone provide some helpful insight on where it's going wrong.

Comment: Tag this with Java if you're going to post Java code

Comment: Try doing the computation on a piece of paper. Does it really solve the problem?

Comment: @rici I might be getting biased while running it on paper because I'm not able to think where exactly its getting wrong given the logic.It will be a great help if you can point out something.Thanks

Comment: Ok, two things. First, you cannot compute (huge_n/huge_d)%1000003 as (huge_n%1000003)/(huge_d%1000003). (Try 2,000,000/1,000,000). Second, you want to do rank += n/d at each step, but you are computing rank = (rank + n)/d. The first one won't apply on your example, but the second should be immediately obvious when you use a pencil-and-paper computer.

Comment: Ps: those aren't the only problems, i think. You need to try an example with three different symbols.

Comment: @rici " but you are computing rank = (rank + n)/d"?? Where did you find that in the above code. What I'm doing there is I'm calculating the product of  all the repeated elements and then doing rank = rank/rep_fact_product .. I don't know where did you find I'm doing  (rank + n)/d. Can you locate that part or elaborate how my code is computing that.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read if you fixed the indentation. But in broad outline, findRank is `for i in 0 to n-1: { Compute numerator; rank += numerator; Compute denominator; rank /= denominator; }`

Comment: Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22643546/1566221) seems like a solution. It uses the optimization of working right-to-left, but the principle is the same.