# N-th permutation algorithm for use in brute force bin packaging parallelization (containing the same item more than once)

Tags: parallel-processing, permutation, bin-packing

I've written a small [open-source 3D bin packaging library](https://github.com/skjolber/3d-bin-container-packing) with a brute-force packager for use in real-time calculation of web shop order shipping cost. Many orders contain a small number of items, making brute-force a fair supplement to other algorithms.

As orders can contain the same item more than once (i.e. repeated / duplicate / identical elements), I've gone with the lexographical permutations algorithm.

Now I'm attempting to add some paralellization / multi-threading and have found [a few algorithms for calculating the n-th lexographical permutation](http://www.zrzahid.com/k-th-permutation-sequence/). However none take into account that orders can contain the same items more than once.

Ideally I would be able to divide the number of permutations by the number of threads, and have each thread calculate its starting point and run a specific number of iterations.

Does such an algorithm exist?

--

UPDATE:

Yes, [it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642151/finding-the-ranking-of-a-word-permutations-with-duplicate-letters). Java code adapted from linked answer:

```
public static int[] unrank(int[] frequencies, int rank) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642151/finding-the-ranking-of-a-word-permutations-with-duplicate-letters

    int count = 0;
    for(int f : frequencies) {
        count += f;
    }

    int permutationCount = 1;
    int first = firstDuplicate(frequencies);
    if(first == -1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            permutationCount = permutationCount * (i + 1);
        }

        // use classic n-th lexographical permutation algorithm
        throw new RuntimeException("Not implemented");
    } else {
        for(int i = frequencies[first]; i < count; i++) {
            permutationCount = permutationCount * (i + 1);
        }
        for(int i = first + 1; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
            if(frequencies[i] > 1) {
                for(int k = 1; k < frequencies[i]; k++) {
                    permutationCount = permutationCount / (k + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return unrank(frequencies, count, permutationCount, rank);
    }

}

private static int firstDuplicate(int[] frequencies) {
    for(int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
        if(frequencies[i] > 1) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}   

private static int[] unrank(int[] frequencies, int elementCount, int permutationCount, int rank) {
    int[] result = new int[elementCount];

    for(int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
        for(int k = 0; k < frequencies.length; k++) {
            if(frequencies[k] == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            int suffixcount = permutationCount * frequencies[k] / (elementCount - i);
            if (rank <= suffixcount) {
                result[i] = k;

                permutationCount = suffixcount;

                frequencies[k]--;
                break;
            }
            rank -= suffixcount;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And for running

```
@Test
public void testUnranking() {
    int count = (7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1) / ((4 * 3 * 2 * 1) * (3 * 2 * 1));
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        int[] frequencies = new int[2];
        frequencies[0] = 3;
        frequencies[1] = 4;

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(NthPermutationRotationIterator.unrank(frequencies, i + 1)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are searching is a ranking algorithm for permutations with duplicates, so far i know there doesnt exist one, in the answer of the thread ( [Finding the ranking of a word (permutations) with duplicate letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642151/finding-the-ranking-of-a-word-permutations-with-duplicate-letters) )you will find one without multithreading. I have read some where but dont know where anymore. That you can improve the complexity by the usage of some tree.

Comment: Or rather the unranking; was able to adapt the pyhton code to my requirements perfectly.