# Algorithm - find middle of permutation with repeating elements

Tags: algorithm, compression, permutation, pseudocode

We have n repeating symbols in a sequence. I want to find the middle permutation, if they were ordered by occurring symbols:
`a: 2, b: 1, c: 1`
=>

```
1 aabc
2 aacb
3 abac
4 abca
5 acab
6 acba !!!!
7 baac
8 baca
9 bcaa
10 caab
11 caba
12 cbaa
```

The middle is `acba`
Can I find this in linear time?
Another OK is to find the first k symbols of the middle permutation.

By the way this is for an optimization of Arithmetic Coding.

Comment: You are missing `aacb`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642151/finding-the-ranking-of-a-word-permutations-with-duplicate-letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642151/finding-the-ranking-of-a-word-permutations-with-duplicate-letters) (The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22643546/2034787) by David Eisenstat includes an unranking function.)

Comment: @גלעדברקן I think this might be it.

Comment: @M-- no, cause it requires the opposite - unranking. I haven't tested it yet, though